# Type mismatch when trying to read results of passthrough query

Tags: vba, ms-access, office365

Why do I get a type mismatch error when I try to read the results of this passthrough query? The goal is to read the results of a stored proc. For speed, I'd like to execute it as a passthrough so that it runs faster. I made sure that `WOActivityStates` exists and when I double click it in the pane on the left it runs just fine.

```
Private Function GetActivityStates()

   Dim strSQL As String
   Dim con As ADODB.Connection
   Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
   Dim intPauseState As Integer
   
   CreatePassThruQuery "WOActivityStates", "exec spGetActivityStates '" & strWO & "' "
   
   Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("WOActivityStates") 'ERROR IS HERE

   Do While Not rs.EOF
      'code...
      rs.MoveNext
   Loop
   
ExitLabel:
   Exit Function
   
ErrLabel:
   ErrHandler Err.Number, Err.Description
   Resume ExitLabel

End Function
```

Comment: Is `CreatePassThruQuery` a sub you wrote? What is that line of code doing?

Comment: @topsail woops, yea, it just creates a pass through query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CurrentDb.OpenRecordset` opens a DAO recordset, not ADODB.

So your code will work with

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
```

Comment: To this day I still don't understand the difference between DAO and ADODB lol...

Comment: Well... you should. :D They are quite different. In this case you should use DAO primarily (or always). https://ss64.com/access/syntax-dao-ado.html @TheMortiestMorty